# Why do the bass lines of some songs sound sharp to me?

Tags: bass-guitar, pitch

I'm listening to the radio. Bob Marley's "Three Little Birds" came on and I was reminded that every time I hear this song the bass guitar, on the lowest note of the backing lick (or whatever you would call it) always sounds, to my ear, ever so slightly sharp.

I've noticed this before on other songs, too. I've always imagined that it's probably inaccuracies on a fretless bass, but have not found anyone else mentioning it, so I assume it must be me.

Is this a common phenomenon - where very low notes are not accurately heard?

Comment: Sounds fine to me.Not sure it's using fretless.

Comment: I'm quite prepared to accept that it's my ear

Comment: Do you mean the intro, where the piano doubles the bass fundamentals? That does sound a bit out of tune to me, rest of the song not. But – fretted bass guitars can certainly have some inaccuracies, especially short-scale ones.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - No it's all the way through.

Comment: I feel like I experience this as well, not just when listening to music, but also when tuning the E string on my double bass (though I've thought this was universal).

Comment: The particular example you gave is not tuned to A=440, it's about 20 cents flat, so that could certainly contribute to the feeling that something's off.

Comment: This was closed as opinion-based, but I'd like to see this question (edited to be more general and) reopened.  I already see an objective answer as to why the bass might sound sharp using inharmonicity.  I'm more interested, however, in the phenomena that I and a few other people have noticed- that harmonically rich bass and baritone register sounds (e.g. sawtooth waves) seem to go sharp at higher volumes.

Comment: @Edward Maybe because the fifth generated by the harmonic serie is a bit sharper that the one of equal temperament? This will accumulate when you go to higher harmonic number. Maybe, that's the fifth that sound a bit sharp, and not the fundamental!

Comment: I'd also be in favor of reopening this question. And I don't think it's opinion-based. It's about a subjective musical experience, and what's wrong in asking where that experience is coming from and what other musicians experience in similar situations?